# SQL Server 2008 Connection String Help Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have inherited an ASP.NET project containing a connection string with the DataSource set to:

```
"Data Source=.\\\sql2008"
```

I have not seen anything of this type before. Can anyone explain what the `.\\\` means? Also, what is the correct technical term for the part set to `sql2008`?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The period (.) indicated sql server is running on the same box as the asp.net application.

My hunch is the connection string you posted was pulled out of a c# string literal. The \\ is really just a single slash, but you need to escape it in C# and the escape character is another \.

The sql2008 is the INSTANCE NAME. Sql server can be installed multiple times on a host. The default instance, of which there can be only one, can be reference without the \InstanceName suffix. You can have multiple NAMED INSTANCES. Using the named instance suffix in the connection string is how you designate which instance you are connecting to.

EDIT:
If "datasource=sql2008" works then perhaps your server name is sql2008 and your database is installed as the default instance. You can determine if you are using a named instance by inspecting the services control panel applet. If you are using a named instance, the sql service will be listed as "SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER$INSTANCENAME)".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have an instance called "sql2008" on the local machine, but asp.net cannot connect. It is throwing an error. "The server was not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections." Do you have any idea why this might not work?

Comment: Is the service running? Can you connect to it from any other tool? like osql.exe?

Comment: Yes, it is running. I have now established that I can connect using "Data Source=sql2008", but NOT "Data Source=.\sql2008". Do you have any idea why? I need to adjust SQL Server on a new machine to match the config on an old one where "Data Source=.\sql2008" used to work.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to a local instance of sql server running upon the machine that the application is deployed upon. sql2008 is the name of the sql server that is being connected to.

Comment: Thanks for you help. So, at the moment, I have a server called "sql2008" on my local machine. Should that be correct? The problem is that ASP.NET cannot connect, and is throwing an error. "The server was not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Comment: `sql2008` is the name of the SQL Server **instance**, to be precise (not the machine). There can be any number of SQL Server instances running in parallel on the same machine - distinguished from one another by means of the **instance name** (which shows up in the connection string)

Comment: So, can you explain why "Data Source=sql2008" works, but "Data Source=.\sql2008" does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I use this so if this will help you:

```
Data Source= server_name; Initial Catalog=database_name; User ID=user_id;Password=password
```

or try to do so:

```
Server=.\server_name;Database=database_name; User ID=user_id;Password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

The **". \"** always means from the current position in local

In .NET you can escape special characters by either putting an @ in front of the string or using a special value to represent the character you want to escape. In this case you can use \ to represent a \

**".\\"** == **@".\"**

So for me

**"Data Source=.\\SQLServer2005"** equal **@"Data Source=.\SQLServer2005"**

but

**"Data Source =.\\SQLServer2005"** or **"Data Source =.\\\SQLServer2005"**

I do not see what that could mean ...

Do you can try this ?

```
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        String connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password" 
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```

Lexique:

**Data Source** : Sql server address,attention if it concerns an instance "SQL EXPRESS" -> please add   `..myadress..\SQLEXPRESS`

**Initial Catalog**: DataBase name from your sql server

**UserId**: User account created on sql server to access the database defined

**Password**: it's password ^^

Comment: Thanks for your help too. OK, so if I use the connection string "DataSource=sql2008" it works, but DataSource=".\\sql2008" does not work. Can you explain what this means in terms of configuration of SQL Server please? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok I change my answer to add a can clarter more .. But. \ \ \ Is strange to me

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right: .\\\ actually is due to escaping. Please ignore the exta "\" characters. So, the actual string (ignoring escaping) that does not work is "Data Source=.\sql2008" but, "Data Source=sql2008" works. What is the difference (in terms of SQL Server)? What would I have to do in SQL Server to make "Data Source=.\sql2008" work? The reason for my somewhat strange question is that we do not have access to the source code to change the connection string. Instead, we have to make our new SQL Server instance match our old one.

Comment: With you edit configuration files "Host"? this is strange. Normally we always start by defining the address and then we add the instance name .. Maybe your machine is named "SQLServer2008" by chance? And that is why "data source = sql server 2008" works? otherwise I do not understand ..